# TFS Build: Disk space error even though there is enough space

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have a build (TFS 2017 Update 1) that is failing on the `Copy Publish Artifacts` step with the following error:

```
2017-05-23T14:31:37.9464650Z ##[error]System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
2017-05-23T14:31:37.9464650Z 
2017-05-23T14:31:37.9474630Z    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2017-05-23T14:31:37.9474630Z    at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
2017-05-23T14:31:37.9474630Z    at System.IO.FileInfo.CopyTo(String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
2017-05-23T14:31:37.9474630Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.CopyFileInfoItem(FileInfo file, String destinationPath, Boolean force)
2017-05-23T14:31:37.9474630Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.CopyDirectoryInfoItem(DirectoryInfo directory, String destination, Boolean recurse, Boolean force)
```

I can prove it is not an actual disk space issue because running a build for the same solution (but different branch) runs just fine.  It seems to be caused by the addition of a new control to the solution, that results in a subfolder in the drop folder.

Is it possible to have the `Copy Publish Artifacts` step properly copy subfolder content?  Or do I need to find a way to get those files in not a subfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, the issue was with the mini-match string.  I changed it to the [recommended value](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts) for all files and subfolders, and it works now.

By using `**\*` instead of `**` it now works.
[image]